# Append to existing file on SFTP server via pysftp

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp, pysftp

I have one file named `Account.txt` in SFTP server, and I'm trying to appending a line to this file. This is my effort:

```
from io import StringIO
from pysftp import Connection, CnOpts

cnopts = CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None
with Connection('ftpserver.com'
                ,username= 'username'
                ,password = 'password'
                ,cnopts=cnopts
                ) as sftp:
    with sftp.cd('MY_FOLDER'):
        f = sftp.open('Account.txt', 'ab')
        data='google|33333|Phu|Wood||true|2018-09-21|2018-09-21|google'
        f.write(data+'\n')
```

When I run this above code, the file was overwritten, instead of appended.  So, How can append new line but still keep the old lines in the file?

For example:

**Account.txt file:**

```
facebook|11111|Jack|Will||true|2018-09-21|2018-09-21|facebook
facebook|22222|Jack|Will||true|2018-09-21|2018-09-21|facebook
```

And now I want to add line "google|33333|Phu|Wood||true|2018-09-21|2018-09-21|google" to the file.
The result I'm expecting:

**Account.txt file**

```
facebook|11111|Jack|Will||true|2018-09-21|2018-09-21|facebook
facebook|22222|Jack|Will||true|2018-09-21|2018-09-21|facebook
google|33333|Phu|Wood||true|2018-09-21|2018-09-21|google
```

Hope you guys can understand. Leave a comment if you don't. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me with OpenSSH SFTP server.

Maybe it's a bug in Core FTP server.

You can instead try manually seeking file write pointer to the end of the file:

```
with sftp.open('Account.txt', 'r+b') as f:
    f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
    data='google|33333|Phu|Wood||true|2018-09-21|2018-09-21|google'
    f.write(data+'\n')
```

Answer (score -1):

An addition to Martin's answer:

When using `r+b`, it will fail if the file does not exist yet. Use `a+` instead if you want the file to be created if it does not exist, in a similar way to [Difference between modes a, a+, w, w+, and r+ in built-in open function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r-in-built-in-open-function/1466036#1466036).

Then no `f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)` will be needed:

```
with sftp.open('test.txt', 'a+') as f:
    f.write('hello')
```

Comment: The OP knows that the right way is to use the `a` mode. The point of this question is that the `a` mode does not work on that particular server.

Comment: Indeed, the `b` is wrong. But it's ignored by Paramiko. Only `a` remains.